# puma server is not starting in SSL mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma, ramaze

I am starting puma server like below

```
puma -b ssl://sstp.localhost.domain.com:7000?key=/private/etc/apache2/ssl/sstp.localhost.domain.com.key&cert=/private/etc/apache2/ssl/sstp.localhost.domain.com.crt
```

but it is serving content only in http mode. 
on requesting

```
https://sstp.localhost.domain.com:7000/path/file.js
```

I get the error

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

sstp.localhost.domain.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I have used open ssl to self sign the certificate

I am using puma 1.6.3  as recommended.I was using 2.8 earlier, downgraded now   as recommended by this thread `https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/350`

I am using google chrome browser, the response is same on every browser

Note: I use ramaze a framework for mocking purpose (`http://ramaze.net/`), Ramaze starts Webrick in port 7000 hence am tied to use port 7000

The logs read like below

```
$ puma

W [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082]  WARN | : No explicit root folder found, assuming it is /Users/<username>/path/mock-server
D [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082] DEBUG | : Using webrick
I [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082]  INFO | : WEBrick 1.3.1
I [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082]  INFO | : ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
D [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082] DEBUG | : Rack::Handler::WEBrick is mounted on /.
I [2016-09-01 10:22:56 $2082]  INFO | : WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2082 port=7000
D [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] DEBUG | : accept: 127.0.0.1:50218
D [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] DEBUG | : accept: 127.0.0.1:50217
E [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] ERROR | : bad URI `?\x13?'.
E [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] ERROR | : bad URI `?\x13?'.
localhost - - [01/Sep/2016:10:23:04 BST] "\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03?T?e\x1D?6?\x04?C??\x16???\x06!Vjm??\x1AW&p(??\x04\x00\x00"?+?/?,?0̨̩?\x14?\x13?\t?\x13?" 400 290
- -> ?\x13?
D [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] DEBUG | : close: 127.0.0.1:50217
localhost - - [01/Sep/2016:10:23:04 BST] "\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03?Pi'Zߑ\x04!/?\x13m??@?M?f?)?4?d??4$١\x00\x00"?+?/?,?0̨̩?\x14?\x13?\t?\x13?" 400 290
- -> ?\x13?
D [2016-09-01 10:23:04 $2082] DEBUG | : close: 127.0.0.1:50218
D [2016-09-01 10:23:07 $2082] DEBUG | : accept: 127.0.0.1:50220
D [2016-09-01 10:23:07 $2082] DEBUG | : accept: 127.0.0.1:50221
E [2016-09-01 10:23:07 $2082] ERROR | : bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03?yiS\x7Ff??݄[???3I-Z\a\t?L??>C?Ŧ???\x00\x00"?+?/?,?0̨̩?\x14?\x13?\t?\x13?'.
E [2016-09-01 10:23:07 $2082] ERROR | : bad URI `?\x13?'.
localhost - - [01/Sep/2016:10:23:07 BST] "\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03P1?\x00V?0?r???y/??:;???҈y?s?c?G\x17?\x00\x00"?+?/?,?0̨̩?\x14?\x13?\t?\x13?" 400 290
- -> ?\x13?
```